# How to retrive Group mail box names for outlook profile using MAPI program?

Tags: delphi, outlook, mapi

Is there a way to retrieve added group mail boxes name for particular outlook profile through extended MAPI program?

Comment: Where does your code run? Do you already have an active MAPI session? Or do you only know the profile name?

Comment: i am having the "profile name". I want to get the all the group mailboxes name which is linked with particular profile in Delphi using Extended MAPI program.

Comment: "linked" as in added to the "open these additional mailboxes" in the Exchange provider options dialog? Or the list of mailboxes that the current user has the right to open?

Comment: Mailboxes which is under "Open these Additional Mailboxes" option.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise to go with [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) which you can call with COM from Delphi. Redemption comes with profman.dll which gives you access to Outlook profiles.

Here's some example VBS code that I used a couple of years ago to dump all added mailboxes to an xml file (conversion to Delphi should not be too hard):

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, WshShell
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

' Load TXMLDocument Class
Include("XMLClass.vbs")

' MAPI constanten
Const PR_DISPLAY_NAME = &H3001001E
Const PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W = &H3001001F
Const PR_MDB_PROVIDER = &H34140102
Const PR_PROFILE_HOME_SERVER = &H6602001E
Const PR_PROFILE_HOME_SERVER_DN = &H6612001E
Const PR_PROFILE_MAILBOX = &H660B001E
Const PR_PROFILE_SERVER = &H660C001E
Const PR_PROFILE_SERVER_DN = &H6614001E
Const PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_NAME = &H6607001E
Const PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_SERVER = &H6608001E
Const PR_PROFILE_USER = &H6603001E
Const PR_PST_PATH = &H6700001E
Const PR_SERVICE_UID = &H3D0C0102
Const PR_STORE_PROVIDERS = &H3D000102

' GUID constanten
Const MailboxGuid = "13DBB0C8AA05101A9BB000AA002FC45A"
Const pbExchangeProviderDelegateGuid = "9EB4770074E411CE8C5E00AA004254E2"

' omgevingsspecifieke gegevens
Const cHomeFolder = "U:\"

' public variabelen
Public objProfiles, objProfile, objServices, objExchService

' XML Object
Dim  xmlDoc
Set xmlDoc = New TXMLDocument
xmlDoc.Create("delegateMailboxes")

'Profman object aanmaken (profman.dll, moet in de c:\windows\system32 map staan, registreren met regsvr32)
Set objProfiles = CreateObject("ProfMan.Profiles")

' Open Default Outlook Profile
Set objProfile = objProfiles.DefaultProfile

Set objServices = objProfile.Services

' Zoek Exchange Service
Dim ServiceIndex, objService, objProviders, ProviderIndex, objProvider, objProfSect
For ServiceIndex = 1 To objServices.Count
   Set objService = objServices.Item(ServiceIndex)

   If objService.ServiceName = "MSEMS" Then
      Set objProviders = objService.Providers

      For ProviderIndex = 1 To objProviders.Count
         Set objProvider = objProviders.Item(ProviderIndex)
         Set objProfSect = objProvider.ProfSect

         ' Gekoppelde mailboxen gebruiken de Exchange Delegate Provider
         If objProfSect.Item(PR_MDB_PROVIDER) = pbExchangeProviderDelegateGuid Then 
            xmlDoc.AddRecord("delegateMailbox")
            Call xmlDoc.AddElement("PR_DISPLAY_NAME", objProvider.DisplayName)
            Call xmlDoc.AddElement("PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W", objProvider.DisplayName)           
            Call xmlDoc.AddElement("PR_PROFILE_MAILBOX", objProfSect.Item(PR_PROFILE_MAILBOX))
            Call xmlDoc.AddElement("PR_PROFILE_SERVER", objProfSect.Item(PR_PROFILE_SERVER))
            Call xmlDoc.AddElement("PR_PROFILE_SERVER_DN", objProfSect.Item(PR_PROFILE_SERVER_DN))
         End If   

      Next

   End If

Next

xmlDoc.SaveFormatted(cHomeFolder & "\delegateMailboxes.xml")
xmlDoc.Free
Set xmlDoc = Nothing

WScript.Quit(0)

Function Include (Scriptname)
   Dim fso, objFile
   Err.Clear
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Scriptname = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\" & Scriptname

'    WScript.Echo("Including " & Scriptname)  
   Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(Scriptname)
   ExecuteGlobal(objFile.ReadAll())
   objFile.Close
   Include = Err.Number
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to

1. Call MAPIAdminProfiles to retrieve IProfAdmin
2. Call IProfAdmin.AdminServices specifying the profile name (get back ImsgServiceAdmin)
3. Find the service with PR_SERVICE_NAME == "MSEMS" (there can be more than one).
4. Call IMsgService.AdminProviders
5. Find "EMSDelegate" providers.

You can see the data and play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IProfAdmin or IMAPISession | AdminServices.